# Как сделать, чтобы после клика по кластеризованной метке на карте - новые метки отображались ближе к центру карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как сделать, чтобы после клика по кластеризованной метке на карте - новые метки отображались ближе к центру карты.
Имеется:

```
map = new ymaps.Map(...);
...
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager(...);
//Делаю так, но это не по фен-шую
objectManager.clusters.events.add('click', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
     $('ymaps.ymaps-2-1-60-zoom__minus.ymaps-2-1-60-zoom__button.ymaps-2-1-60-float-button.ymaps-2-1-60-user-selection-none').trigger('click'); },500);
});
```

Как правильно написать конструкцию ниже для решения этой задачи?
    map.setBounds(objectManager.getBounds(), {zoomMargin: 30});
К какому событию менеджера объекта привязать эту конструкцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день. Можно использовать опцию zoomMargin https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#param-options.zoomMargin , выглядит это так:

```
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: true
        zoomMargin: 100
    });
```

Пример : https://jsfiddle.net/roqf4ea9/

Comment: se0ga, большое спасибо. Это работает.